# Should I use OR with multiple subqueries or UNION all the subqueries, when using Exists?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

I'm writing a query to determine if a record exists in the db according to some conditions met in other tables.

Now I came up with a situation where I need to know what is the best approach:

either OR the subqueries:

```
SELECT * from table as tbl WHERE
Exists
(SELECT 1 FROM t1 WHERE t1.id = tbl.id)
OR Exists
(SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE t2.col2 = tbl.col2)
OR Exists
(SELECT 1 FROM t3 WHERE t3.othercol = tbl.somecol)
```

or Use UNION without ORs:

```
SELECT * from tbl WHERE
Exists
(SELECT 1 FROM t1 WHERE t1.id = tbl.id
 UNION
 SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE t2.col2 = tbl.col2)
 UNION
 SELECT 1 FROM t3 WHERE t3.othercol = tbl.somecol)
```

I need this to be the best in performance, thus the question.
Some fields/columns might not be indexed and this  might happen in a set of different columns not just 3, maybe even more than 1 per subquery/table.

For best resolution I'm going to publish some complex examples here:
How would this be with joins?

```
SELECT * from table as cli WHERE
Exists 
        (

        SELECT 
            1
        from 
            tbl_import_line_reference as l,
            tbl_import_doc as d
        WHERE
            d.import_key = l.import_key AND
            CAST(Left(d.doc_date,8) as  DATE) BETWEEN  LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 day AND  NOW()
        AND
            l.prod_ref like '---fmidref%'
        AND
            d.doc_type ='F'
        AND 
            d.car_miposreg_ext_id = cli.car_miposreg_ext_id
        )

    OR
    Exists
        (

        select 
            1
        from 
            tbl_import_line_reference as l,
            tbl_import_doc as d
        WHERE
            d.import_key = l.import_key AND
            CAST(Left(d.doc_date,8) as  DATE) BETWEEN  @data_final + INTERVAL 1 day AND  NOW()
        AND
            l.prod_ref not RLIKE '---fmidneo|---fmidevo'
        AND
            l.act_code = 5
        AND
            l.act_subcode = "7"
        AND
            d.doc_type ='F'
        AND 
            d.car_miposreg_ext_id = cli.car_miposreg_ext_id
        )
```

After that this: http://pastebin.com/gTFBFurV became this: http://pastebin.com/y13xKcMg

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: Seeing the actual tables and relationship basis to the Exists clauses.  Sometimes, doing left-JOIN to the other tables, working with keys can be faster than exists since exists are processed per row, but joins take advantage of joins vs explicit re-querying.

Comment: My full queries are long and boring this is about general question that may apply to various scenarios thus using pseudo-code, @Strawberry . In this particular case the subqueries might use more than one column for the "checking" I'll update.

Comment: Well, in a nutshell, the answer is NEITHER, but without seeing some of schema I'm just not smart enough to help further.

Comment: @Strawberry, what would you suggest then? ...

Comment: Is the first one even valid syntax? Shouldn't it be `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT...) OR EXISTS (SELECT ...) OR EXISTS (SELECT ...)`?

Comment: @Barmar you are right lemme correct it.

Comment: I suspect the first will be most efficient, because of short-circuiting in `OR`, especially if you order the subqueries in order of most likely match. If the first subquery matches, the second and third won't have to be done at all. The UNION has to perform all the subqueries.

Comment: @Barmar: yes, it is valid syntax, though it's not standard. MySQL evaluates the subquery as a boolean. If the subquery returns a 1, it's true. We'd add a `LIMIT 1` clause on that subquery to avoid a "returns more than 1 row" error.

Comment: @spencer7593 But the argument to `EXISTS` has to be a subquery, not a boolean. Or is that the MySQL extension, that it allows `EXISTS <boolean>`?

Comment: @spencer7593 thanks I'll ADD the `LIMIT` clause, I already used it in similar situations...
@spencer7593 and @Barmar I meant to use it like @barmar said, it was a flawed query!

Comment: Downvoting a serious person in need of help is just mean... Could I get some Upvotes for support? Also please write some answers! @Barmar, I liked your comment about efficiency please put it in an answer, I think it qualifies.

Comment: @DRapp, comparing your scenario of left-joined tables with my "EXISTS OR" and taking into account Barmar's efficiency comment, the left-joins would all _have_ to be processed much like the UNION and therefore take longer than the "EXISTS OR" _if_, for example, the first subquery/table was a positive match. would it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using left-joins, it uses the index only (provided your table has an index on each respective "ID", "col2" and "othercol" basis.  The index is very fast and does not need to go to raw pages to confirm it "exists" or not.  The where clause just cares about any of the elements NOT NULL (indicating it DOES exists in the underlying table)

```
SELECT 
      tbl.* 
   from 
      table as tbl
         LEFT JOIN t1
            ON tbl.id = t1.id
         LEFT JOIN t2
            ON tbl.col2 = t2.col2
         LEFT JOIN t3
            ON tbl.somecol = t3.othercol
   WHERE
         t1.ID is not null
      OR t2.col2 is not null
      OR t3.othercol is not null
```

Comment: So, you can get `null`/`not null` information directly from the index, making that query never touch the data pages for `t1`, `t2`, or `t3`?  That's pretty slick.

Comment: @zebediah49, correct, and lets say a person only cared about t2 by the matching col2 AND some "status = 123".  The AND clause could be added at the left join and only qualify if both by ID AND the status -- just make sure that the criteria of the join is part of the index to be properly optimized.

Comment: How, nice answer! Since I have it ready with "EXISTS OR" I'll benchmarked it before and after applying your solution  and post the results here :)

Comment: How about the update? how would I _left_ -join that?

Comment: A query of this form has a potential to return "duplicate" rows from `tbl`, if there are more than one "matching" rows from t2 (or t3).

Comment: Regarding duplicates I added a `group by cli.car_miposreg_ext_id` see my lastest update on paste BIN (<http://pastebin.com/y13xKcMg>). I gained 28% in query speed, quite nice. Also that made me reflect on another query that took 60%  less time after optimizing! thanks!

Comment: @spencer7593, I do agree with you, but with the generics, I could not specifically identify as such.  Sometimes, they could be lookup tables where there would only be a single instance, but again, lack of specificity was as good as I could offer.